# how to show specific field use ebean relation

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

...
is my code

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "destination_country_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "countries", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Country country;
```

...

is the result

```
"id": 139,
"country": {
            "id": 1,
            "iso": "AU",
            "name": "Australia",
            },
"country_id": 1
```

...

I hope the result is

```
"id": 139,
"country": "australia",
"country_id": 1,
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code and change to private in var country

```
@Column(name = "name", table = "countries")
public String country_name;
```

this is a new my code

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "destination_country_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "countries", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Country country;

@Column(name = "name", table = "countries")
public String country_name;
```